# unable to run android project as eclipse considering it as a library

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, project

I was working with Google Map in Eclipse ADT. I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) and [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) tutorial. Everything went smooth. However, right now, when I tried to build the project, Eclipse is saying

```
 "Android Library projects cannot be launched"
```

I tried again from the beginning thinking that I might have clicked some wrong check boxes however the error still persist. The only library project I have imported is the google play services libs.
Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: You cant launch library projects. Import the lib projects to your Android project and launch that project.

Comment: @Dhina, My main project is not a lib project. It was the main project. I use google play services as the only lib.

Comment: Did you check Is Library in your project ? Just make sure you havent.

Comment: I have checked the google play services as a library project for my project abd

Comment: Googleplay services is already a lib project you dont need to check anywhere just import to your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming because of the fact that you have checked the box "Is Library" in the Properties option for your project. Please uncheck that checkbox and you wont see that error again. Your proejct is a app project which is referencing Google Play Services, which is a library its referencing but your project is not a library, hence you have to uncheck that checkbox as library projects cannot be launched as they do not contain .apk file.

```
Here are the steps to run the Map project as a app project and not as a library:
 - In the Package Explorer, right-click the library project and select Properties. 
 - In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right. 
 - **Do not** select the "is Library" checkbox and click Apply.
 - Click OK to close the Properties window.
```

Make sure that you have declared your fragment activity in your manifest file with Internet and Map Receive permissions.